# Transform Meteor template into PDF file

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to transform a Meteor template into a PDF file. I found [this package](https://github.com/ongoworks/meteor-pdf/) using [this library](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) that transform HTML into PDF.
The problem is... I don't understand how to get the HTML of my template. I have for the example a test template (in Jade) :

```
template(name="test")
  h1 Title 1
  p Hello, world!
```

And these functions (according to the tutorial) :

```
var specialElementHandlers = {
  '#bypassme': function(element, renderer)
  {
    return true;
  }
};

Template.autotest_verdict_content.events({
  "click #generate-pdf": function ()
  {
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'letter');
    var source = $("#verdict-content").get(0);   // I tried this (from a rendered template)
    var source = Template.test;   // And this (the template I want to transform)
    doc.fromHTML(source, 0.5, 0.5, 
    {
        'width': 7.5,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.output('dataurl');
  }
});
```

I only create a PDF file with "undefined" string in it. I think I misunderstood how Template works... Can someone explain it to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you do sth like this (as stated in package docs):

```
Template.autotest_verdict_content.events({
    "click #generate-pdf": function (){
    Blaze.saveAsPDF(Template.test, {
      filename: "test.pdf", // optional, default is "document.pdf"
      x: 0, // optional, left starting position on resulting PDF, default is 4 units
      y: 0, // optional, top starting position on resulting PDF, default is 4 units
      unit: "in", // optional, unit for coordinates, one of "pt", "mm" (default), "cm", or "in"
      format: "letter" // optional, see Page Formats, default is "a4",
      elementHandlers: specialElementHandlers
    });
}});
```

Comment: Okay... I have to learn how to read a doc... Sorry for this and Thank you.